# How can I run nodejs server not using commands terminal

Tags: node.js

This is my server:

```
[...]
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {

    // watching the xml file
    fs.watch('../json/notificheJSON.json', function(curr, prev) {
    // on file change we can read the new xml
        fs.readFile('../json/notificheJSON.json', function(err, data) {
            if (err) throw err;
            // parsing the new xml data and converting them into json file
            var json = JSON.parse(data);

            // send the new data to the client
            socket.volatile.emit('notification', json);
        });
    });
});
[...]
```

This is my client:

```
[...]
// creating a new websocket
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8080');

// on every message recived we print the new datas inside the #container div
socket.on('notification', function (n) {
    // convert the json string into a valid javascript object
    //var _data = JSON.parse(data);
    for(var i = 0; i < n.notifiche.length; ++i) {
        if(n.notifiche[i].id_ricevente == <?php echo $id_utente; ?>){
            var numero_not = n.notifiche[i].numero_notifiche ;
        }
    }
    $('#notify, #la_mobile').html(numero_not);      
});
[...]
```

Actually, I run my server using the command line:

```
nodejs server.js
```

I would like to run my server on remote hosting. How can I do it?

Comment: Depends on the remote host. In some form or fashion that command will need to be ran. Have you tried contacting the host? You'll have to ensure the host has node.js installed too, and do npm build/install etc.

Comment: try nodejitsu or heroku, both have nodejs support and have a free alternative which will be useful for development. I wouldn't recommend it in an initial state of a project though, as you can get more insights (or the same but easier) if you run it locally

Comment: Yes, my host supports node.js, but I don't know how to run my server.js without the command nodejs server.js

Comment: Ask your host. If they support node.js, then they likely also have a way for you to connect to the server via ssh, or they have a node deployment process.

Answer (score 0):

In some form or fashion you need something that will execute node and your application. If you are using remote host that how that works depends on the host, checkout their documentation to see what they say about running node applications.

There are a couple of options for executing node. You can do it using [nom scripts](https://www.npmjs.org/doc/misc/npm-scripts.html). Another option is using an init script, but since you on a remote host I doubt that is the route you want to take unless you are on a VPS.